# specific column [Remove elements up to last zero element, then remove elements from first zero element to the end]

Tags: matlab, matrix

This is a very specific question. I have an M*3 matrix. The first column contains M set of elements. It may follow this.

```
0
0
0
0
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
0
0
0
0
0
```

My interest is only 1s and corresponding other column values. I can remove zeros get a new set of matrix with only 1s, but sometimes it may follow this:

```
1
1
1
0
0
0
0
0
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
0
0
1
1
```

When the situation is like above I want to disregard 1s in the beginning and remove all the elements in M*3 matrix up to the first 1, then when it reaches second start of zeros in the column it can remove all the values to the end of the column. (so it will be 13*3 matrix).

I'm doing this in matlab. 
Thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

Let's call your matrix A:

```
firstCol = A(:, 1);

indices = find(firstCol);
check = find(diff(indices) ~= 1);

if (isempty(check) )
    Afinal = A(indices, :);
else
    indices2 = indices(check(1)+1:1:check(2));
    Afinal = A(indices2, :);
end
```

Afinal should be the output you're looking for.

Comment: It's working, but can you explain me how it works? Thank you :)

Comment: The first line extracts the first column. The second line gets an array containing the index of each entry in the first column that is a 1. The third line takes the difference between successive values in indices and finds all of the indices that do not differ by 1 (in other words, the indices of 1s that are separated by zeros). If check is empty, it means we have the first case you listed and we simply extract the rows we want. Otherwise, the first and second values in check will indicate the indices that surround the middlemost run of 1s. This works for the cases you listed.

Comment: I'm getting this error in some cases:Attempted to access check(2); index out of bounds
because numel(check)=1.

Error in abc2 (line 162)
    indices2 = indices(check(1)+1:1:check(2));

Comment: I also have situations where the column may look be as follows:  0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0                        I would like to always consider the middle portion of 1s. Any help is appreciated... Thanks.. :)

Comment: I'm observing binary values along the line to determine magnitude of a line.